# How to run eventquery.vbs every hour in windows server 2003

Tags: batch-file

I am using following command to extract specific data in time interval

```
echo %data%
cscript eventquery.vbs /fi "Datatime eq 04/04/2017,4:00:00PM-04/04/2017,10:00:00PM,7:00:00PM" /v /fo csv>eventlog.txt
```

I am able to get what i require. But i want to make this as a Task scheduler .bat file and get it run every hour. I want to get last hours data everytime its run manually or by task scheduler.

Please can anyone help me to automatize this thing in windows batch file ?

Comment: Configure a scheduled task in task scheduler being triggered every hour.

Comment: `schtasks /create /sc hourly /st 00:05:00 /tn "every_hour" /tr "cscript eventquery.vbs /fi \"Datatime eq 04/04/2017,4:00:00PM-04/04/2017,10:00:00PM,7:00:00PM\" /v /fo csv>eventlog.txt"` ?

Comment: But i want the input parameter of timer range to be automatically just 1 hour before the running time whenever the schedule task is executed. i don't want to manually put 4:00:00PM to 7:00:00PM.

Comment: then wrap the command in batch file and calculate there the range?